# How to lazy-load more data in a List view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to load the next set of data when the user scrolls down to the last item and append them to the List view.

In the NetworkManager(), I add `self.currentPage += 1` to the DispatchQueue, but I don't know if it's working.

**NetworkManager.swift**

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var cards = [CardInfo]()
    private var currentPage = 1
    
    func fetchData() {

        
        if let url = URL(string: "https://schoolido.lu/api/cards/?page=\(currentPage)") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.cards = results.results
                                self.currentPage += 1
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

In this view, I want to fetch the data every time the user scrolls to the last item and load more items if necessary.

**IdolListView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct IdolListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    
    @State private var searchString = ""
    @State var thumbImage: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(networkManager.cards) { card in
                NavigationLink(destination: IdolDetailView(
                    card_idolized_image: card.card_idolized_image,
                    idol_name: card.idol.name,
                    idol_name_jp: card.idol.japanese_name,
                    idol_school: card.idol.school,
                    idol_year: card.idol.year,
                    idol_subunit: card.idol.sub_unit), label: {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https:\(card.round_card_image)")) { thumbImage in
                            thumbImage.image?.resizable()
                        }
                        .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(card.idol.name)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            
                            Text(card.idol.school)
                                .font(.callout)
                                .padding(.bottom, 0.25)
                            
                            if let sub_unitString = card.idol.sub_unit {
                                Text("\(card.attribute) • \(card.idol.year) year • \(sub_unitString)")
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            } else {
                                Text("\(card.attribute) • \(card.idol.year) year")
                                    .font(.caption)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchString)
            .navigationTitle("School idols")
            
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
        }
    }
}

struct IdolListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        IdolListView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To lazy-load more data when scroll to the last row. You might wanna use something like this:

Let's say we have a RowItem as each row view. then u can use task modifier to preload more item if needed.

```
List(networkManager.cards) { card in 
    RowItem(card: card)
        .task {
            networkManager.loadMoreIfNeeded(lastAppearedCard: card)
        }
}
```

So in your NetworkManager, you can have loadMoreIfNeeded function that you can do the logic whether you should load more.

It might look something like this:

```
func loadMoreIfNeeded(lastAppearedCard: CardInfo) {
      guard lastAppearedCard.id == cards.last?.id else {
            return
      }
      fetchData()
 }
```

I think it is good to have a function like this, so if you were to support api that take offset or limit as params, you can add the logic inside the function.